# Link processing.js file to canvas

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I try to link a .pde file to the html element canvas but I'm somehow failing to.
This is the code I'm trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas" data-processing-sources="sketch/sketch.pde">Un canvas devrait s'afficher</canvas>
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anybody anybody help me?

Comment: Please share the errors you have in the console (if any). Press F12 to open it

Comment: I have two errors:

processing.min.js:18 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/andreabourguignon/Desktop/sketch/sketch.pde' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: sketch/sketch.pde processing.min.js:18 ==> XMLHttpRequest failure, possibly due to a same-origin policy violation. You can try loading this page in another browser, or load it from http://localhost using a local webserver. See the Processing.js README for a more detailed explanation of this problem and solutions.

Comment: That's because you're not using a real web server (you're clicking on your HTML file in your mac). Use a web server for your test. Either install one on your computer, or use a online one

Comment: Ho ok, I thought it should work without being on a server... Thank you :)

Comment: Please be aware that Processing.js was discontinued in December 2018. Don't start new projects with it, use the Processing-recommended https://p5js.org library instead if you want to write sketches for the web.